# Complex shipping logics

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

In Craft Commerce 2, we have two shipping categories:

1. PostNL, which is one of the Dutch main shipping methods, which we use for packages that fit in the mailbox.
   For this category we use the weight as a measurement, and the consumer pays the whole shipping price based on the total weight of the order.
2. Shipped by courier, for products that don't fit the mailbox we send them by courier.
   For Courier the shipping costs are different per product per zone and the consumer pays the shipping per product.
   So when we have 10 crates, the consumer pays the shipping cost 10 times.

I am looking for a way to add the shipping costs per product per zone and when someone orders a product in both categories only the courier category will fit.

I could think of two routes:

- creating multiple shipping categories that fit each product separately; then the question would be how would I set this up best.
- create a plugin that reads a specific field(s) per product and zone; then the question would be what would be the best place to hook this in.